# Problems in enabling GPU rendering in cycles render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have a Geforce GT 710 GPU with all the latest drivers installed. Somehow, i can't  enable CUDA in the Blender USer Preferences.
[image: This is the screenshot of the same:]

Comment: Have you installed [Cuda Toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)?

Comment: If the drivers are up to date and it doesn't show up, the card is most likely not supported. I cannot find it listed on https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus I have not heard of the need to install CUDA Toolkit. That is not required for rendering to work. Anyway, this might not be a huge problem in this particular case because even if it was supported, 192 CUDA cores are probably going to be outperformed by most processors that you want to use for 3d work.

Comment: Okay thaks I got a new card and everything is okay now. :)